# Upload File with .NET for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8, windows-store

Now that I have come to the realization that I can not use the normal `.NET` to write my Windows Store apps, I am trying to wade through the mess that is `.NET` for Windows Store apps. My latest discovery is that the `System.Net.WebClient` class is missing, and I needed to use it to upload a file. Had this class been there, I would have done something along the lines of:

```
webClient.UploadFile("http://my.website/upload.php?a=" + someParam, "POST", filepath);
```

Unfortunately, I can't do this in .NET for windows store. How would I achieve a similar functionality using only .NET for windows store?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try HttpClient class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx - it has Post method, and if you look at this answer[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data), it shows how to create multipart data for file upload.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry if I'm being dense, but it seems as if several other classes used in that example are not supported. For example `FileStream`, `httpWebRequest.GetResponse()` and `httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` all aren't found, and `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` seems to be missing, or at least moved, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get reference to a `StorageFile`. Using `FileOpenPicker` would be one way:

```
var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
var file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

Then use the following code to upload the file (I haven't tried it as I don't have an upload page handy, but it should work):

```
using (var randomStream = (await file.OpenReadAsync()))
{
    using (var stream = randomStream.AsStream())
    {
        using (var content = new StreamContent(stream))
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
        }
    }
}
```