# Blob Storage in windows store apps using C#

Tags: c#, azure

hello guys is there a way to upload image file in the windows store apps using azure blob storage in c#? also i want to use the development storage first before converting to cloud storage. any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Upload file for Windows Store Apps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15608604/1384539

Use Blob storage:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/

Comment: thanks for the answer! but the 2nd link you have provided is only applicable to asp.net or any webpaged environment. i have found a answer but i dont know how to ultilize this: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-store-apps/

Comment: the article you found explain. you need to install the azure storage library through nuget.

Comment: @hack.luminence: I would offer some caution about the article you found. It requires you to place the storage account credentials in the application. If someone reverse engineers you app, they could gain access to your account and use it for a expensive and potentially illegal actions. I would recommend instead that your store app leverage something like Azure Mobile Services to interact with Azure Storage.

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey of course im willing to do that but would like to develop first to the local storage then after i develop i will then migrate to azure mobile services and azure storage